# How to make navbar collapse when using mobile phone

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I am using bootstrap and I want to make my navbar collapse when browsing on mobile phone, I check the documentation but I didn't make it.

Here is the code I write:

```
 <!-- row 1 -->
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">

    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li><a href="http://www.abiworld.org" class="nav navbar-brand">ABI DIVE</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#survey">Survey</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Can you show me how to change the code to make it collapse?

Thanks!

Comment: which bootstrap version?

Comment: 3.1.1   @KheemaPandey

Comment: did you try to replace `navbar-inverse` with `navbar-default`

Comment: Yes, but that will only change the background color of the navbar

Comment: can you share a working Demo  please

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you read the code from [Bootstrap's documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar), A responsive navbar is made with this HTML code:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
    </div>

    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
  </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>
```

Things that are missing from your code sample:

- Not wrapped in `container-fluid`
- No button for toggling the navbar when elements are collapsed
- Menu elements are not wrapped in `collapse navbar-collapse`

I made a working [Bootply](http://www.bootply.com/118291) from your example (Click the phone icon to see it collapsed).